# Trying to get my code updates to publish to my angular website but still getting an error in the console

Tags: c#, node.js, angular

Does anyone know how to fix this error. I am building an angular app in VSC and when I am publishing up dates I keep getting this.

__vite-browser-external:console:3 Uncaught Error: Module "console" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "console.error" in client code.  See http://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
at Object.get (__vite-browser-external:console:3:11)
at app.component.ts:5:23

When I go to the suggested website I still get no answers.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you think anyone can help you without looking at the line that has the error? Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Search for `import { error } from "console";` in your code and remove it if you have imported it into client code